# Server error when opening Authorized Applications page

Tags: bug, 500-server-error, se-applications

When I try to load the 'Authorized Applications' page, with the link on the [Edit profile & settings page](/users/edit/current):

[image]

something bad happens:

[image]

I've tried a couple of sites, but only on Stack Overflow it's properly working for me. It could be related to something specific to my account; another user just posted an answer that it's working for them, and the page works for my sock puppet account too. Still, I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: No repro for me. How many apps do you expect to have in that list?

Comment: The corresponding page on SO lists 9 apps for me.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) Windows  10

Comment: Hmm, I have 16 apps listed, so it is not that the number of apps is limited to 6 to 8 ....

Comment: No repro here either. And I have a tendency to get broken stuff (seriously, we were sent a whole box full of smashed glassware once). Chrome latest version Win 10, and Firefox 67 too.